# Web авторизация по smart-card (смарт картам)

Tags: php, javascript, symfony3

Необходимо реализовать авторизацию в **веб** прилажении (**Symfony 3.x**) по **smart-card** (**смарт картам**), подскажите как это можно реализовать? Может есть уже готовое решение для браузеров? Может расширение какое-нибудь?

Comment: По номеру карты?

Comment: Получается что так, в общих чертах это должно выглядеть так: юзер подошел к ПК, провел карту по магнитному считывателю (или еще что) и у него прошла авторизация в проекте symfony. В общем мне необходимо как то получить номер карты на стороне symfony. Подскажешь что-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю, одним браузером тут обойтись невозможно, необходим считыватель таких карт, который уже в свою очередь, будет взаимодействовать с бэкэндом. А как этот считыватель будет взаимодействовать с бэкендом тут уже необходимо читать документацию к этому самому считывателю

Comment: Наверняка уже есть готовое решение, не встречал? В поисках этого решения находил обсуждения 12го года, 5ти летней давности, по-этому решил поискать уже готовое решение для этого, что бы не изобретать велосипед) Может кто находил такое?

Comment: Тоесть тут еще зависит от того, какой у меня считыватель?

Comment: Так а сам считыватель умеет отправлять запросы в веб? Ну или может он, к примеру взаимодействовать с БД? Сам бэкэнд - дело второе, не думаю что там будет сложно

Comment: Честно говоря даже не знаю, наврятли думаю, что такое встроено в сам считыватель

Comment: @SHTIKOV в любом случае считыватель как-то должен взаимодействовать с компьютером, к которому он подключен, прочтите документацию.

Comment: Спасибо за советы)